# Find the adjacency matrices for $K_n$ and $W_n$

Tags: graph-theory

Find the adjacency matrices for $K_n$ and $W_n$.

> The adjacency matrix $A = A(G)$ is the $n\times n$ matrix, $A=(a_{ij})$ with  $a_{ij}=1 $ if $v_i$ and $v_j$ are adjacent, $a_{ij}=0$ otherwise.

How i can start to solve this problem ?

Adjacency matrix for $W_n$ :

$$ \left[
        \begin{matrix}
        0 & 1 & 0&0 &\cdots & 1&1\\
        1 & 0 & 1&0 &\cdots&0&1\\
        0 & 1 & 0&1 &\cdots&0&1\\
        0 & 0 & 1&0 &\cdots&0&1\\
        \vdots & \vdots& \vdots & \vdots & \ddots  &\vdots &\vdots \\
        1 & 0 & 0 &1&\cdots &0&1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 &1&\cdots&1&0
        \end{matrix}
\right] $$

Answer (score 1):

Well for the complete graph $K_n$ one sees that all vertices are connected by an edge. As such each $a_{ij}=1$. Hence $A(K_n)$ is the matrix consisting of all ones. One can deduce similar arguments for $W_n$. Notice that for the wheel graph, there is one special point and the other points are all identical. You could try to give an answer for small $n$ and then generalise your findings.

Comment: Can you check my answer ? is it true for $A(W_n)$ ?

Comment: Yes that seems to be correct :)